# How many votes on questions by sock puppets does it take to suspend his account?

Tags: discussion, support, sock-puppets

If a sock puppet votes on a question or an answer, how many times can it do that before the account gets suspended or deleted?

Comment: It's not public information, for the obvious reason that if it was, every sock could be handled in just the way to escape the system.

Comment: Friendly tip: if you have another account which is suspended and you created this new one to bypass the suspension.... please, don't. Delete this account and wait for the suspension to end. Otherwise if caught, the mods might extend the suspension period on your actual account, and it will be justified.

Comment: The exact number for a vote reversal is kept secret, but voting fraud is kind of the sort of thing that someone who intends to engage with good intentions dosen't. Alternate accounts shouldn't *ever* interact with the main user.

Comment: If you use a secondary account to do something you can't do with your main one, it will be suspended.  That includes voting on the same post with both accounts, voting on posts of the main account, and much, much more.  There is no line where it suddenly becomes not okay.  Just don't do it.

Comment: @fbueckert This should be the top answer. You nailed it.

Comment: @Bieber: "*Is anything wrong with it?*" A little bit. The only reason someone would need to know this is if they're trying to game the system. So people probably think you're trying to game the system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: it's not relevant. One vote is enough.

---

I don't think it's related to the amount. Also, the sock account is **deleted** or merged with the main account, and the suspension is applied to the main account, otherwise it's pointless.

Once a moderator finds out about a sock abusing votes, the action would be instant, whether it was one vote or 1000 votes.

The amount does have effect on the suspension length though, e.g. one "bad" vote might lead to only one day suspension as warning, while 1000 bad votes can easily give a full year suspension to the main account.